# Grunt connect task not actually starting app

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I am trying to get my grunt connect task working correctly, and I'm stumped. I have an angular app that I want to run, and it sits in a folder like this:

```
dev/myApp
   |--- /modules
   |--- /directives
   |--- /vendor
   |--- /etc...
   |--- index.html
```

I am using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to manage state and routing in my app, starting with a default state like this:

```
    myApp.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/home",
            views: {
                ...
```

I want to do something very simple: use grunt's [connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) task runner to open a browser and navigate to `http://localhost:8888/myApp/#/home`.

I am using the connect task list so:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    base: 'dev/'
  },
  devserver: {
    options: {
      port: 8888,
      open: {
        target: 'http://localhost:8888/myApp/#/home'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The grunt connect documentation seems pretty clear, yet my window always opens to plain-old `localhost:8888`. If I manually type in the URL I want, it works fine.

I've tried looking for examples online, but most tutorials I have seen are explaining the middleware option, which I don't believe I need for something this simple. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Per @Michael's suggestion, I used grunt-open, with the following config in my gruntfile:

```
open: {
  devserver: {
    path: 'http://localhost:8888/myApp/#/home'
  }
}
```

This now works great.

Thanks!

Comment: strange. did you try open: 'http://localhost:8888/myApp/#/home' this is also a valid configuration.

Comment: @Michael I added grunt-open and was able to get it working. if you phrase your comment as a question I'll accept! Thanks!